# Speed up query time via live stream or anyway

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Speed up query time via live stream or anyway

Target : Speed up  query response no matter in any format (**JSON format** or **Postgres raw format**)

- The rails console showed it took 1180.4ms in **ActiveRecord**

  ```
  Completed 200 OK in 2122ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1180.4ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
  ```
- The same query took `1180.4ms` in PostgreSQL console

  ```
   Total runtime: 909.894 ms
  ```

And the total response time is about `2122ms` I think Rails takes up the extra time `2122ms - 909.894 ms`

Is there any way can boost the performance ?

How to get it ? Thanks

### Here's my current implementations,

`sample 2` is slower than `sample 1` (I looked up the `Completed 200 OK in xxxx ms` to comapre theirs performance)

### sample 1

```
  get_query_result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(build_query).values

  render json: Oj.dump(get_query_result.to_a, mode: :compat)
```

### sample 2 (Streaming version: I thought this version will be faster, but it didn't)

```
    send_file_headers!(:type => 'application/octet-stream', :filename => "result.backup.txt")
    stream = response.stream
    get_query_result.each do |record|
       stream.write record.to_s
    end
```

Comment: Have you see http://www.webascender.com/Blog/ID/553/Rails-Tips-for-Speeding-up-ActiveRecord-Queries#.VKRO-aZoVD4 they have some really good database optimization techniques

Answer (score 0):

I think that's about all you can do. I don't think you can do any better with the code you have.